# Prevent uninstall app - Honor 6A

Tags: applications, uninstallation

After some research, I can't prevent apps to be uninstalled on my phone - Honor 6A.
When an app will be uninstalled, I would want a pop-up with a password.
I see a lot of app which can do this feature, but it doesn't work on my phone.
I've done the authorization on settings/security/usage access for the app i want to protect, but it doesn't work.
It looks like the phone Honor 6A have something to block this feature.
Do you know this problem and can you help me to solve it ?
Thanks.

Comment: What would be the usage scenario? Only users can uninstall apps, therefore if you decide to uninstall an app you can also enter the password. You hand your device away to a different person cerate a separate Android user account and switch to it.